# responseError always get -1 status in httpInterceptor

Tags: angularjs

I config the $httpProvider to deal with the 401 error in responseError, but the rejection.status always -1, i can saw it was 401 in network with chrome DevTools.

[image: httpInterceptor config]

[image: 401 error in network]
[image: get -1 error in responseError]

My restful published by Spring Boot, and i test it with postman, it response in a very short time.
[image: my restful response in postman]

The java code like this:
[image: Spring Boot code]

Comment: `status: -1` error could mean that there was a timeout and server is not responding

Comment: My Restful API seems to be well, it response in a very short time and give the full response content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved, the restful api is not the same origin with AngularJs. 
When 401 error send by restful api, it triggering a CORS exception. I add `response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` in java and resolve this problem.